What is the correct way to use padding when using Python's pyca/cryptography library to encrypt and decrypt large files in chunks?
I'm attempting to use the pyca/cryptography library to decrypt potentially very large (average ~20 GB, but as big as in the hundreds of GBs) files that will have been encrypted using a non-Python implementation of AES-128-CBC.
I'm planning to read the file into memory in ~2 GB chunks due to its size/memory limitations.
I'm doing a little bit of initial prototyping/testing using files of various sizes and I am curious if I'm employing PKCS7 padding/unpadding correctly.
Although there are a few examples of using padding with Python crypto libraries out there, they all assume relatively small plain/ciphertexts that can easily be operated on in-memory in one shot.
I've been testing the below code on a file that is only ~500 bytes in size just to experiment with padding.
My initial "working" attempt was this:
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding import PKCS7

key = os.urandom(16)
iv = os.urandom(16)

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv))

# Encrypt in 128-bit blocks temporarily while testing padding changes on a small file
chunk_size = 16 # 2 * 1024 ** 3

original_file_name = "test.txt"
encrypted_file_name = f"{original_file_name}.aes"
decrypted_file_name = f"{original_file_name}.dec"

# First encrypt my original file
with open(original_file_name, "rb") as fin, open(encrypted_file_name, "wb") as fout:
  encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

  padder = PKCS7(128).padder()
  while unencrypted_bytes := fin.read(chunk_size):
    padded_bytes = padder.update(unencrypted_bytes)

    encrypted_bytes = encryptor.update(padded_bytes)

    fout.write(encrypted_bytes)

  fout.write(padder.finalize())
  fout.write(encryptor.finalize())

# Then decrypt my encrypted file into a different file
with open(encrypted_file_name, "rb") as fin, open(decrypted_file_name, "wb") as fout:
  decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

  unpadder = PKCS7(128).unpadder()
  while encrypted_bytes := fin.read(chunk_size):
    decrypted_bytes = decryptor.update(encrypted_bytes)

    unpadded_bytes = unpadder.update(decrypted_bytes)

    fout.write(unpadded_bytes)

  fout.write(unpadder.finalize())
  fout.write(decryptor.finalize())

However, inspection of the encrypted file via hexdump revealed relatively obvious padding bytes, because I wasn't encrypting padder.finalize():
  while unencrypted_bytes := fin.read(chunk_size):
    padded_bytes = padder.update(unencrypted_bytes)

    encrypted_bytes = encryptor.update(padded_bytes)

    fout.write(encrypted_bytes)

  fout.write(padder.finalize())
  fout.write(encryptor.finalize())

I've ultimately settled on this for the encryption/decryption:
with open(original_file_name, "rb") as fin, open(encrypted_file_name, "wb") as fout:
  encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

  padder = PKCS7(128).padder()
  while unencrypted_bytes := fin.read(chunk_size):
    padded_bytes = padder.update(unencrypted_bytes)

    encrypted_bytes = encryptor.update(padded_bytes)

    fout.write(encrypted_bytes)

  fout.write(encryptor.update(padder.finalize()))
  fout.write(encryptor.finalize())

with open(encrypted_file_name, "rb") as fin, open(decrypted_file_name, "wb") as fout:
  decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

  unpadder = PKCS7(128).unpadder()
  while encrypted_bytes := fin.read(chunk_size):
    decrypted_bytes = decryptor.update(encrypted_bytes)

    unpadded_bytes = unpadder.update(decrypted_bytes)

    fout.write(unpadded_bytes)

  fout.write(unpadder.update(decryptor.finalize()))
  fout.write(unpadder.finalize())

With the above, I don't seem to get any errors, nor are my padding bytes obvious in the ciphertext. My question boils down to this: am I using the padder/unpadder correctly? In particular, am I correct to finish with:
  fout.write(encryptor.update(padder.finalize()))
  fout.write(encryptor.finalize())

when encrypting, and:
  fout.write(unpadder.update(decryptor.finalize()))
  fout.write(unpadder.finalize())

when decrypting? I believe so, as the order is pad-then-encrypt in one direction, so decrypt-then-unpad makes sense in the other.

Yes, the output of padder.finalize() must be passed to encryptor.update(). The padded output is still plaintext and must be encrypted. And of course you've got to reverse everything for decryption. As an aside, 2GB is probably way bigger than the buffer you need. You can experiment but I doubt you'd get much of a benefit beyond 1MB. You should probably create a small class that properly applies padding and encryption, and decryption and unpadding.

Your code looks correct to me. The encryption/decryption processes and the padding/unpadding processes both work as a stream, where you call update for each chunk of input and finalize for the last part of the output. Thus a loop of for input_chunk in …: p2.update(p1.update(input_chunk)), followed by p2.update(p1.finalize()) and p2.finalize(), where p1 is the first process to apply and p2 is the second process. Padding is performed on the plaintext, thus when encrypting, p1 is padding (transforming plaintext into padded-plaintext) and p2 is CBC encryption (transforming padded-plaintext into ciphertext). When decrypting, p1 is CBC decryption (transforming ciphertext into padded-plaintext) and p2 is unpadding (transforming padded-plaintext into plaintext).

Note that CBC is only secure if you can trust the ciphertext's integrity, or more precisely its authenticity. That is, you must be sure that the data you pass to the decryptor is genuine data prepared by the encryptor. This makes CBC ok if you have other controls over the data integrity, for example if it's stored on physical media and you'd know if it was tampered with. If a malicious actor can modify your ciphertext, not only can they inject fake data, but they can even leverage the decryption process to decrypt data — a padding oracle attack. For this reason, CBC is somewhat deprecated, and new designs should use authenticated encryption.
